# create textview while running program

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

i want to create a program that read HTML code from website and then display some strings from it (something like search something in google and print the results on my app). 
I want to dynamically create textboxes on the screen depends on how much results im getting from the html (like if i get 10 results so i want the program to create 10 textviews each one set for each result) now im already built the part that grab the html and convert it to strings array, all i need now is the part that dynamically print them.

edit: i'm sorry, i didn't mean something like listview i'm looking for something that is more like android gallery menu that the text is in the boxes instead of the images.

Comment: Try a ListView. You can set a simple ArrayAdapter with your strings array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ListView to Show your Dynamic Data...

**Listview loads the dynamic data through Adapter, You can update, delete, insert the data from adapter and ultimately from listview at any time, See [this tutorial](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php) for more help..**

Answer (score 0):

You can create views dynamically in Java and display them to complement your static XML:

```
TextView tv = new TextView();
tv.setText(result1);

/*Put type here*/ layout = findVIewById(R.id.yourviewname);
layout.addView(tv);
```

I agree with others suggesting that a ListView would be much more appropriate for your use case: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html